# iOS XCTest take Screenshot

Tags: ios, xctest

I'm aware of useful tools like facebook/ios-snapshot-test-case but what I'm after is the ability to store a png of the output of a unit test that interacts with a view.

Ideally, I'd like to get it off the simulator and onto the environment running XCode, so that after I run my batch of tests, I have a folder of screenshots of what was rendered.

Does anyone know of a framework or workflow that is good for taking screenshots off the simulator?

Comment: Are you asking how to get an image from the simulator to your Mac?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function that programmatically captures the UIWindow to a jpg or png.  The image can be persisted to disk.

When your test case completes it can call this function.

Comment: UIView also has a snapshot method that can be called to get a UIImage of what's in the view. Call this on your active view control let's root view.

Answer (score 0):

There are more third party libraries to make screen shots in app, you don't need to program it yourself.
I needed it just once and I tried KSScreenShot. It wasn't perfect but for my purpose it was enought.

Answer (score 0):

The awesome [snapshot](https://github.com/fastlane/snapshot) can do this. I use it to generate the App Store screenshots.